# Displaying data from database in PHP, first and last name going into same column

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to display members from my database using PHP, however the last name goes in with the first name and I'm not quite sure why... Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<?php
$mysql_db_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_db_user = "alex";
$mysql_db_password="";
$mysql_db_database="gym";

$con = mysql_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password) or die("Could not connect database");

mysql_select_db($mysql_db_database, $con) or die("Could not select database");

$query = mysql_query("select * from users WHERE Category='Member'");

echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Users ID</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
</tr>";

while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['user_id']."<br>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['First_Name']."<br>" . "</td";
echo "<td>" . $row['Last_Name']."<br>" . "</td";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table";
?>
```

Comment: You aren't closing the </td> tags

Comment: html error, look at the td's

Comment: As all the answers have indicated, the `td` tags are not closed.  But make sure to notice your `table` tag as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't closing the  tags. Syntax highlighter would show the error.

```
while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['user_id']."<br>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['First_Name']."<br>" . "</td"; <-----------
    echo "<td>" . $row['Last_Name']."<br>" . "</td"; <------------
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing your `<td>` tags properly

```
echo "<td>" . $row['First_Name']."<br>" . "</td>";
                                             //^here
echo "<td>" . $row['Last_Name']."<br>" . "</td>";
                                             //^and here
```

So the output is all one cell with both variables printed inside

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the td on your first name field.

Just change

```
</td
```

to

```
</td>
```